# Autovectorize array of unvectorizable processes in VS 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, vectorization

Suppose you have the following code:

```
class Unit
{
private:
    float _outDel = 0;

public:

    float Process()
    {
        float rnd = rand();
        float out = rnd + _outDel;
        _outDel = out;
        return out;
    }

    void Process(int frames, float *out)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            out[i] += Process();
    }
}

class UnitBank
{
private:
    Unit _unit[128];

public:

    float Process(int frames, float *out)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
            _unit[i].Process(frames, out);
    }
}
```

The purpose of this is to sum up an array of 128 processes, each of which produces some numbers.

In essense, Unit module can't be vectorized, because of backward data dependency (_outDel variable).

But, is it possible VS 2012 "being set with some flags" produces a *vector* of Unit modules (UnitSSE) and then uses these to compose a UnitBank class with 32 sse units? Something like this:

```
class UnitSSE
{
private:
    float128 _outDel = 0;

public:

    float128 Process()
    {
        float128 rnd = rand();
        float128 out = rnd + _outDel;
        _outDel = out;
        return out;
    }

    void Process(int frames, float128 *out)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < frames; i++)
            out[i] += Process();
    }
}

class UnitBankSSE
{
private:
    UnitSSE _unit[32];

public:

    void Process(int frames, float128 *out)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
            _unit[i].Process(frames, out);
    }
}
```

So, is it possible VS 2012 to generate such optimization automatically?

Comment: Does this code even compile? You are calling "_unit[i].Process(out);
" whereas the Unit class has no Process overload with a single parameter

Comment: Oooops, seems I forgot to add a frames variable to the place of interest! (but I have checked a few times before posting). I have changed nessessary parts, now everything should be ok.